# App freezes if a lot of images are loading in iOS 9

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, ios9, sdwebimage

My App freezes since iOS 9 if I load a lot of images. Our web server sometimes has problems to deliver all images (gateway timeout), so the app freezes until timeout. There is no error and the app is just fine after that. I'm using SDWebImage and RestKit. I can reproduce the freeze in the simulator. I didn't have this problem with iOS 8. Before I send a request to our server, I remove all cached responses: `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];`

The app freezes in `semaphore_wait_trap`.

The last line of RestKit thread is `self.cachedResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:requestOperation.request];`.

The last line of SDWebImages thread is `if (![[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:_request])`.

If I pause the debugging during the freeze, I get this output in the debug navigator window (The `YPI`classes are my own): [image: debug navigator window]

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the reason: `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];` before sending the requests caused the UI hang. After removing these lines and disabling `NSURLCache` for the whole app, the problem disappeared:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, initially I thought it was a core data concurrency issue at my side, but after disabling the cache, it works fine.